# com.qualcomm.qti.smartsearch library is missing when trying to install Dialer.apk

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop

I decided to get some stock AOSP apps on my samsung galaxy s4 i9500 Android 5.0.1 stock.

When I try to install Dialer.apk I get the following:

```
xx@ixx:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ ./adb install ~/Dialer.apk 
3739 KB/s (4715532 bytes in 1.231s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/Dialer.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]

**I get the following in log cat while installing the app+:**

W/PackageManager( 3175): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.android.dialer-1
W/PackageManager( 3175): com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerException: Package com.android.dialer requires unavailable shared library com.qualcomm.qti.smartsearch; failing!
W/PackageManager( 3175):        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.updateSharedLibrariesLPw(PackageManagerService.java:6522)
W/PackageManager( 3175):        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.scanPackageDirtyLI(PackageManagerService.java:6944)
W/PackageManager( 3175):        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.scanPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:6697)
W/PackageManager( 3175):        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installNewPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:12883)
W/PackageManager( 3175):        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:13695)
W/PackageManager( 3175):        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.access$2500(PackageManagerService.java:323)
W/PackageManager( 3175):        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$8.run(PackageManagerService.java:11005)
W/PackageManager( 3175):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
W/PackageManager( 3175):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/PackageManager( 3175):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
W/PackageManager( 3175):        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
W/PackageManager( 3175):        at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
D/PackageManager( 3175): doPostInstall for uid{-1}
```

I tried to find com.qualcomm.qti.smartsearch library in package which I got apk from, but there is no such library. Can you please have a look and advice?

Comment: Don't know if it's relevant, but the i9500 doesn't use a Qualcomm chipset, but a Samsung one. It's the i9505 which uses a Qualcomm chipset.

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes you are right, but I got apk file from cyanogenmod  ROM for i9500, so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to install the app in the such way.
You should copy it into /system/priv-app/Dialer/ (create the directory if necessary) and set proper access rights.